# Alignment is not proper in android

Tags: css, cross-browser

The issue is when i see in windows & iphone the css property is working fine. but in android its not working as expected.

on Iphone & windows

[image: On iphone & windows]

On android

[image]

My css :-

```
width: 25px;
height: 25px;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
font-size: 25px;
line-height: 25px;
color: #6d20c5;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
padding-bottom:2px;
```

Comment: HTML is dynamic... issue is only in css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
display: inline-block;
```

This makes your layout dependent on the `font-size` of the parent container, as it defines the gaps between inline elements, as they are actually spaces. Also, you don't specify an absolute font size in this element itself, which could cause differences.

If precise layout is important for elements like this, rely on more absolute methods. In this case, you could either use absolute positioning as the element has a fixed size, or float the buttons with proper padding inside an absolute sized container.

Given the CSS it would even seem Android is more correct here as you're giving it a bottom padding of 2px, causing the slightly-above-the-middle vertical layout of the characters. This is impossible for me or others to debug properly though as we cannot see which other rules are affecting them, and whether you are using any reset methods like `* { margin:0; padding:0; }` globally.

Comment: cant use position:absolute property. HTML is dynamic. there are basically two divs. outer div has padding:6px property. inner div contains +, - text inside the. so even if I float buttons with proper padding it cause loss in alignments in windows   & iphone

Comment: I agree, `padding-bottom:2px;` is ultimately the problem.

Comment: I use padding bottom for difference cause in the text like height of 'A' is ultimately greater than '+'.

Comment: even if I remove padding-bottom.. then also same problem is there